# Links not working in Wordpress 4.1

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have Wordpress 4.1 application on DigitalOcean.

After installation I found that any other link besides root/home link don't work.

I looked into similair questions and tried:

1) Change permalinks to default settings.

Now links partialy work. I mean they are ugly :`http://104.131.95.146/?post_type=product` instead of `http://104.131.95.146/products`

As suggested I did some troubleshooting from this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Permalinks) :

*Pretty permalinks are available under:
Apache web server with the mod_rewrite module*

But my server is Apache and I checked if mod_rewrite is aviable with:

```
apache2ctl -M | grep rewrite
```

got this message :

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
 rewrite_module (shared)
```

Tried to restart apache and my droplet but still the same problem.

My htacces file inside var/www/html/.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again fixed by myself.

I skipped important part of Wordpress installation.

What I did:

By default, this is 000-default.conf, but your file might be different if you created another configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Inside of this file, we want to set up a few things. We should set the ServerName and create a directory section where we allow overrides. This should look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName server_domain_name_or_IP
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    . . .
```

When you are finished, save and close the file.

Next, we need to enable the rewrite module, which allows you to modify URLs. You can do this by typing:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

After you have made these changes, restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```